# How to add custom event in material components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components

I am trying to build a component such as the following using the mat button toggle component in Angular.

status.component.html

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input id="status1" type="radio" name="status-item" (change)="onSelectStatus($event)">
    <label for="status1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          Status 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <mat-button-toggle-group
            class="status"
            name="status"
            (change)="onToggle($event)"
          >
            <mat-button-toggle value="pass">Pass</mat-button-toggle>
            <mat-button-toggle value="n/a">n/a</mat-button-toggle>
            <mat-button-toggle value="fail">Fail</mat-button-toggle>
          </mat-button-toggle-group>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="status2" type="radio" name="status-item" (change)="onSelectStatus($event)">
    <label for="status2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          Status 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <mat-button-toggle-group
            class="status"
            name="status"
            (change)="onToggle($event)"
          >
            <mat-button-toggle value="pass">Pass</mat-button-toggle>
            <mat-button-toggle value="n/a">n/a</mat-button-toggle>
            <mat-button-toggle value="fail">Fail</mat-button-toggle>
          </mat-button-toggle-group>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

status.component.scss

```
input[name="status-item"] {
  display: none;

  &:checked + label {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

I described only main section of the page above. To the right of the list(it is main section) are the details of the selected item.
My plan is to highlight a selected row of the list and display the details of the selected item on the right side of the page.

So, I think I need a new event besides the built-in events of `mat-button-toggle`

For example `focus`, `click`, and so on. Now it provides only `change` event.

When I click the label of a row, the row is highlighted and selected. But when I click the `mat-button-toggle`, the row isn't highlighted and not even selected.\

I want to select a row to display the details on the right side of the page when I click any parts of the row(label, toggle button, and other parts), so it should be selected when I click the mat-toggle button whether it chagnes or not.

As I mentioned above, it provides only `change` event. So I can't select the row if its value is not changed when I click `mat-button-toggle` of the row.

Is there any possible way?

Comment: The focus event fires if you tab to a button or other element, too. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes, @JSmart523. When I click anywhere(spaces, buttons, toggles, etc.) in the row, the row should be highlighted. So I need to detect events from all parts of the row. That is what I want.

Comment: Who are your users? Can you safely assume a current, standard browser?

Comment: @JSmart523 The browser will be Chrome and Safari. Google chrome is first than Safari. Do you have any idea? And is it related to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You want to highlight a mat-button-toggle element is any element within it is being hovered over, right?

If I'm right, I think this can be done with css of

```css
mat-button-toggle:has(:hover) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

However, I visit StackOverFlow via phone so I can't test it! :-( (Let me know and I'll either remove this paragraph or all-out delete this answer?)

If that works, you might also want to consider [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) as well to highlight anything containing an element being *focused* on.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to manage it with JavaScript? In my case, to the right of the list are the details of that item. When I select one item from the list, I need to display the details of that item on the right.

Comment: Select, focus, or both?

Comment: Either way, this is nowhere in your question and, either way, you can still do it with `:has()` if you have the detail (as opposed to getting it from the server on demand), then first try putting the details there for all choices, each within a `<details>` element, then CSS like `mat-button-toggle details: {visibility: hidden}` and `mat-button-toggle:has(:hover) details: {visibility: visible}` You should be able to make a CSS selector for selected rows and apply the same strategy.

Comment: I am sorry, I updated my question.